# Helping me to prove H axiom in S4.3

Tags: logic, kripke-models

We have frame $\mathcal{F} = (W,R)$  that  $R$ is reflexive and transitive and 
$\forall x,y,z (xRy \wedge xRz \wedge y\ne z \rightarrow yRz \vee zRy)$
,prove
$\mathcal{F} \models \square(\square p \rightarrow q) \vee \square(\square q \rightarrow p )$.

I assume that if $\mathcal{F} \nvDash  \square(\square p \rightarrow q)$ then I must show $\mathcal{F} \models \square(\square q \rightarrow p) $.

so because $\mathcal{x} \nvDash  \square(\square p \rightarrow q)$ I have $\exists y \;xRy((\,\forall z \; yRz \; z\Vdash q) \rightarrow y \Vdash p) $
but I don't have any idea how to get 
$\mathcal{x} \models \square(\square q \rightarrow p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try proving the contrapositive, i.e.:
If for a valuation $\sigma$ we have $\mathcal{F},\sigma \not\models \Box(\Box p \to q) \lor \Box(\Box q \to p)$, then there are worlds $x,y,z \in W$ such that $xRy, xRz, y\neq z$ and neither $yRz$ nor $zRy$ holds. From the first statement you get good candidates for $x,y,z$.

Comment: Thank you so much,you are right ,now I can prove it.